# Identity in each group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Why must the identity be part of each group ? I was wondering about this in the context of "Algebra" by Michael Artin, where the author explains that there is essentially one group of order two.

Comment: I think one way to get an answer is to logically negate the axiom "$\exists e\in G\mid \forall a\in G, ae=ea=a$", and see what "undesired" outcomes you may then have.

Comment: ...with the algebraic structure you are left with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial group $\{e\}$ is the smallest possible group. It is also true that it is a subgroup of every possible group. Hence every group contains the identity.

Of course this a roundabout way of proving the statement, but you don't have to do it this way since identity being a part of every group is built into the definition of a group.

Edit: This, I realized, is not how you prove it, as it assumes that the identity is a part of any group. My answer therefore is wrong. You just have to work with the definition of a group and how that includes the existence of the identity.